# How to get current date - 7 days of data in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The field has a date value in this format : 20230215 : YYYYMMDD

I want to select only those records where date is a date in last 7 days.

Is there a way to achieve this in Snowflake with date format?

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
SELECT 

CASE 
    WHEN (DATECOL = '' AND DATECOL is NULL and DATECOL = 'NULL') THEN '3000-01-01' 
    ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATECOL), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    END AS DATECOL_FINAL

FROM TABLE
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE DATECOL_FINAL > current_date () - 7
```

This code does not work, error : Can't parse ' ' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'
The DATECOL  is varchar (8)

Comment: WHERE DATECOL > now() - interval 1 week;

That is pure MYSQL but it might work hopefully .. let me know and ill mark up a full answer.
(here is the full statement)
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATECOL > now() - interval 1 week

Comment: The date input format is in 20230215 : YYYYMMDD and in snowflake I am trying to code this

Comment: Sounds like Mysql To me .. nothing i typed cared about the format, it just used the DB to format the data .. did you try it and it not work?

Comment: Oh wait .. you want Snowflake to calculate the date and not the datasource?  Not sure why you want to do that on purpose .. trust me .. converting from front end to back end is a pain in the butt .. its best to let the db source just handle it for you.

Comment: Tried as it is, SQL compilation error:

Comment: In Snowflake I have a table which has a column which has date in format : 20230215 : YYYYMMDD . From this table I want to select records which are for last 7 days , meaning where date is a date in last 7 days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251891/discussion-between-shruti-and-easleyfixed).

Comment: Is it stored as an INT?  If so, it might need converted to a date first. WHERE DATE(DATECOL, 'YYYYMMDD') > CURRENT_DATE()-7

Comment: This is varchar (8), the code fails with Can't parse ' ' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'

Comment: There is your problem .. a STRING is NOT a date .. so you can not compare a WORD to a WORD if that makes sense.  CAST AS DATE to convert it .. (God willing).

Comment: ``` SELECT 

CASE 
    WHEN (DATECOL = '' AND BEZDT is NULL and DATECOL = 'NULL') THEN '3000-01-01' 
    ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATECOL), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    END AS DATECOL_FINAL

FROM TABLE ``` Error Can't parse ' ' as date with format 'YYYYMMDD'

Comment: When you want to search for a NULL you don't want to search for the string 'NULL' but rather the value NULL .. same with numbers .. '1' is a Varchar .. but 1 is an Integer.

Comment: I am trying to capture the null, blank etc, but this is not being captured by any code, not sure in snowflake if there is a way to capture any blank etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved the issue in Snowflake

```
WITH
CTE_DATE
AS
(
SELECT 

CASE 
    WHEN (DATECOL <> '' AND DATECOL is NOT NULL and DATECOL <> 'NULL') THEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATECOL), 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    ELSE  '3000-01-01' 
    END AS TEST_DATE,*

FROM TABLENAME WHERE LEN (DATECOL) <> 1
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_DATE WHERE TEST_DATE > CURRENT_DATE()-7 ORDER BY TEST_DATE ASC
```